# Deleting reports generated by JR Server at scheduled duration

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to perform deletion on generated reports (*PDF* files) at scheduled duration.

I am done with Scheduler part. The only thing is to make a method which got logic to delete the bunch of reports generated in between those hours.

1. Is there any *JasperReports API* available which I can use to delete those generated reports from the specified location?
2. How about to use *ResourceLookup*, find resources and delete resources. I don't have much idea about to use it.
3. A small example/link to resources would help

Comment: Are you talking about JR Server?

Comment: IMHO, there is no *JR API* to perform this operation. You should write Java application for this purpose. With *JR Server Web Services* you can delete *JR Server's* resources (templates, datasources, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I don't find any information about JR Server's resource anywhere. Our reports are generated on server at specific location. In this case also JS Server's Resource API cannot be used and used for templates, datasources?

Comment: You can find [guides here](http://jasperforge.org/espdocs/espbrowse.php?id=87&type=folder&group_id=112&parent=87). Yes, I think it can not be used in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You know the directory where to delete the reports.

So, in simple Java, using the lastModified date:

```
File dir = new File("directoryName");

Date deleteStartDate;
Date deleteEndDate;

File[] children = dir.listFiles();
if (children == null) {
    // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
} else {
    for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
        // Get filename of file or directory
        File file = children[i];
        Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
        if (lastModified.after(deleteStartDate) && lastModified.before(deleteEndDate))
        {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know the location and this is simple to do in Java but I was lookin if it could be done through JS Server API. Also there may be the csae when there are thousands of files.